# Estimation in presence of signal dependent noise

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, estimation, maximum-likelihood

Given a model as below:
$$y_1 = x + \eta_1$$
$$y_2 = x + \eta_2$$

where $n_1 \sim N(0,\sigma_1^2)$ and $n_1 \sim N(0,\sigma_2^2)$, $N$ denotes a Gaussian distribution and $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ are known. It is straightforward to find the estimate for $x$ using maximum likelihood:
$$L(x) = p(y|x) = p(y_1,y_2|x)$$
$$L(x) = p(y_1|x)p(y_2|x)$$
$$L(x) = N(y_1;x,\sigma_1^2)N(y_2;x,\sigma_2^2)$$
This can then be solved by taking the derivative of $\ln L(x)$ and equating it to zero to get:
$$\hat{x}_{ML} = \frac{\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}y_1 + \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}y_2$$

However, for the case where the model is as below:
$$y_1 = x + \eta_{h1}$$
$$y_2 = x + \eta_{h2}$$

where $\eta_{h1} \sim N(0,a_1x+b_1)$, $\eta_{h1} \sim N(0,a_2x+b_2)$ and the parameters $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2$ are known. In this case, both error terms are now dependent on $x$. Can I  still derive an estimate for $x$ through maximum likelihood? Are there other methods to derive an optimal estimate of $x$?

Comment: Yes you can. It will be a non easy optimization problem.

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate a little? I'm stuck on which direction to take to solve this problem.